# How to get several values using optarg?

Tags: c++, getopt

I'd like to get more optargs after arguments, but I'm not sure how to do it. I want to call my program like

```
./test -a first second -b third
```

and I can now get only one value after argument -a. When I try to put there two or more, avalue is null.

My code:

```
   char *avalue = NULL;
   char *bvalue = NULL;
   while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "a:b:")) != -1)
     switch (c)
       {
      case 'a':
         avalue = optarg;
         break;
      case 'b':
         bvalue = optarg;
         break;
       case '?':
         if (optopt == 'c')
           fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
         else if (isprint (optopt))
           fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
         else
           fprintf (stderr,
                    "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                    optopt);
         return 1;
       default:
         abort ();
       }

   printf ("avalue = %s\nbvalue = %s\n",avalue, bvalue);
```

Comment: You can't do that. GNU getopt considers your command line no different from `test -a first -b third -- second`. At best you could expect `test -a first -a second -b third` to work.

Comment: Isn't there a way how to get those values "illegaly"? The program will be called like this, so I have to find a way.

Comment: I've got a package I call `ngxgetopt` (next generation extended getopt) that is configurable to require 2 options after `-a`, etc.  It was designed to unify a bunch of retrograde and deviant command line parsing techniques while respecting the original calling conventions.  Contact me by email (see my profile) if you want it.  T'ain't trivial (1500 lines code, 150 lines header, 93 KiB gzipped tar file); comes with a substantial test suite and copious documentation on option conventions.

Comment: Why not just change the specifications of your command line? Something like `-a first,second -b third`? There'll always be *some* character you need for separation, might as well make it something recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

This conventional format requires at most a single argument to each flag. You cannot change it.

However, depending on your shell, you may be able to use quotation marks to "group" multiple *tokens* into a single argument:

```
./test -a "first second" -b third
```

This grouping would take place inside your shell, i.e. before the arguments are sent to your program.

Comment: Another possibility might be `getsubopt()`...probably not in this case, but worth a mention.